# Bootstrap responsive layout design

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I am trying to build the following layout on desktop using Bootstrap v4.3.

[image]

This should translate to the layout below on mobile.

[image]

However, when I run my code, I get the result below.

[image]

Where am I going wrong in the layout in my code?

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid shop-page-main-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3"style="border: 1px solid blue"><!-- Subnav container -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-12 col-xl-12" style="border: 1px solid red"><!-- Subnav content A -->
                    <div class="shop-page-subnav-box">
                        <h3 class="shop-page-subnav-box-header">
                            This is content A
                        </h3>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12"  style="border: 1px solid green"><!-- Subnav content B -->
                    <div class="shop-page-subnav-box" style="margin-top: 10px">
                        <h3 class="shop-page-subnav-box-header">
                            This is content B
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9 col-xl-9" style="border: 1px solid black"><!-- Main content -->
            <div class="shop-page-breadcrumbs">
                <h3 class="shop-page-subnav-box-header">
                    This is main content
                </h3>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: There is no `-xs` in Bootstrap 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

col-xs does not exist in bootstrap 4 layout grid, use `class="col-6 col-lg-12"` on the blocks you are trying to get next to eachother.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

The Problem here is, that when the width of the screen falls below a certain width the container are all "set" to have their own row. So you will probably have to overwrite the CSS.
You could possibly set

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) { .class {max-width: 200px;} }
```

or something in that manner. Don't copy paste, won't work.